# Getting error with creating objects in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an error in the script. At first, when the program starts, everything is fine, all InputFields have coordinates Y -200. But when I delete objects, and then re-create already the Y coordinate -800.

Where is the error?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SpawnText : MonoBehaviour
{
public int text_number = 20;
public GameObject TextPanel;
public GameObject toggle;
public GameObject ct;
private int k;
public GameObject[] obj;
public GameObject[] obj1;
public GameObject textTime;
public GameObject textPrice;
public GameObject InputFieldTime;
public GameObject InputFieldPrice;
private RectTransform rt;
private bool isSettings = false;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    CreateProgram();
}
// Update is called once per frame

//Клик на кнопку настроек
public void SettingsOnClick()
{
    switch (isSettings)
    {
        case false:
            isSettings = true;
            textTime.SetActive(false);
            textPrice.SetActive(false);
            InputFieldTime.SetActive(false);
            InputFieldPrice.SetActive(false);
            for(int i = 0;i < text_number; i++)
            {
                Destroy(obj[i]);
                Destroy(obj1[i]);
            }
            break;
        case true:
            isSettings = false;
            textTime.SetActive(true);
            textPrice.SetActive(true);
            InputFieldTime.SetActive(true);
            InputFieldPrice.SetActive(true);
            CreateProgram();
            break;
    }


    }

private void CreateProgram()
{
    rt = ct.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    int height;
    k = -60;
    height = text_number * 72;
    rt.sizeDelta = new Vector2(0, height);

    for (int i = 0; i < text_number; i++)
    {


        obj[i] = Instantiate(TextPanel, new Vector2(0, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        obj1[i] = Instantiate(toggle, new Vector2(0, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;

        obj[i].transform.SetParent(ct.transform);
        obj1[i].transform.SetParent(ct.transform);

        obj[i].transform.localPosition = new Vector2(-200, k);
        obj1[i].transform.localPosition = new Vector2(-420, k);

        k -= 70;
        obj[i].transform.localScale = new Vector2(1, 1);
        obj1[i].transform.localScale = new Vector2(1, 1);
        obj1[i].GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = (i + 1).ToString();
    }
}
}
```

When program starts

[image]

When delete and create objects

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is not Y but X actually

**But** note that the `RectTransform` is not the same as `Transform`.

What you see there in the Inspector is afaik the [`RectTransform.anchoredPosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform-anchoredPosition.html) **not** the `transform.localPosition`!

Not 100% sure but you should try and use

```
obj[i].GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition = new Vector2(-200, k);
obj1[i].GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition = new Vector2(-420, k);
```